# User Defined Value (Date) is changing within Jmeter test plan

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have user defined variable for date: Date1 | 31-Jul-2018.
Now I am using this variable within my test plan, and on each iteration, I will be decrementing the date too for which I have code in JSR223 processor but that gets executed at the end of first iteration.
The issue I am facing is that in the beginning of the test plan, date is being displayed correctly within my SQL query, but then towards the end of the test plan when I need to use the date again, Date value has changed and showing some random value like - '03-Jul-0208'. Just an fyi  - we haven't reached the Date decrement code yet when i start getting this random value.

Test plan structure:
[image: Test plan]

I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Can you share your code of JSR223 Processor?

Comment: Sure, I can share that. But that has nothing to do with my problem because that code gets executed as a last step and I am using the variable in the middle of my test plan script.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI you have reached the Date decrement code as soon as you executed JDBC_SelectDCNfromTemp sampler first time.

JSR223 PostProcessor is being executed after each [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) in its [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) so most probably the error is in your code which you're unwilling to share.